# Finding similarity of 1 paragraph in different documents with Doc2vec

Tags: python, nlp, doc2vec, opensemanticsearch

how to find one target paragraph or document similar to other lists of documents to the target paragraph that is semantically similar.

```
import os
import gensim
import smart_open
import random
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
# Set file names for train and test data
test_data_dir =('C:\\Users\\hamza\\Desktop\\')
train_file = os.path.join(test_data_dir, 'read-me.txt')
target_file = os.path.join(test_data_dir, 'read-me2.txt')

def read_file(filename):
    
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            data = f.read()
        return data
    
    except IOError:
        print("Error opening or reading input file: ", filename)
        sys.exit()
def read_corpus(fname, tokens_only=False):
    with smart_open.open(fname, encoding="iso-8859-1") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            tokens = gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(line)
            if tokens_only:
                yield tokens
            else:
                # For training data, add tags
                yield gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(tokens, [i])

train_data = list(read_corpus(train_file))
target_data = word_tokenize(read_file(target_file))

# print(target_data)
# print(test_corpus)
model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=50, min_count=2, epochs=40)
model.build_vocab(train_data)
# print(f"Word 'noise' appeared {model.wv.get_vecattr('noise', 'count')} times in the training corpus.")
model.train(train_data, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)
inferred_vector = model.infer_vector(target_data)
sims = model.dv.most_similar([inferred_vector], topn=len(model.dv))
print(sims)
```

Output

[(1, 0.20419511198997498),
(2, 0.1924923211336136),
(0, 0.10696495324373245)]

Now how I can match target data to train data and how I will know how much they are similar is there any way to scale the similarity into percentage?

Comment: Have you tried any flavor of full-text search engines? like [Apache Solr](https://solr.apache.org/) or [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/?ultron=B-Stack-Trials-EMEA-UK-Exact&gambit=Stack-Core&blade=adwords-s&hulk=paid&Device=c&thor=elasticsearch&gclid=CjwKCAjw_ISWBhBkEiwAdqxb9up7AqeWg_jOQIRhCsUgmSRaY-LCyTNemYdv2oekoPVMNhbcv5cTwxoCZAQQAvD_BwE)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the class name `Doc2Vec`, and the fact that it is based on an algorithm called 'Paragraph Vectors', this algorithm for modeling text has no inherent idea what 'paragraphs' or 'documents' are.

It simply takes whatever *texts* you give it – where each text is a list-of-words – & learns a way to plot those texts into a vector-space for comparisons.

So, using it to "match one target document or paragraph in other documents and bring them as a list how much they are semantically similar" is one possible application:

- Train a `Doc2Vec` model with your full set of texts.
- At the end of training, the model will both (a) have learned a vector for each text; (b) have learned how to infer (via the `.infer_vector()` method) vectors for *new* texts that use the same words as the model already knows.
- Look up the exact vector for one of your training texts with `model.dv[tag]`. Get a vector for a new text with `model.infer_vector(list_of_words)`. Compare those vectors using any vector operations you'd like.
- Get a ranked list of known texts (from the training set) that are closest to some target vector with `model.dv.most_similar()` - you can either supply a tag (to name one of the training documents) or a raw vector (via the `positive` argument) as the target point.

If this & the tutorial isn't enough to make progress, you should better explain more about what your data is, what you've tried so far, and where things haven't yet worked – with as much of your code, and precise info about what has and hasn't been achieved yet, as possible.

(It's nearly impossible to give a helpful answer to "guide me through this generic underspecified project". But if you say instead – "I have data D & want to achieve well-described goal G. I've tried X, but only had result or error Y so far, when my ideal result would be more like Z. What would help me get from my progress Y so far, to my desired result Z?" – then it is possible to give tangible tips/pointers/explanations.)

Comment: train_data = list(read_corpus(train_file))
target_data = list(read_corpus(target_file))
model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=50, min_count=2, epochs=40)
model.build_vocab(train_data)
Actually, I have two documents that contain paragraphs regarding noise pollution. Now how I can get how much  *percent* target data is similar to train data. I am a bit confuse how to use model.infer_vector() and then the most_similar function, in the end, to have resulted in a percentage similarity can you help me write code?

Comment: It's better to edit code in your question text, where it can be properly formatted, than these comments. There's not really such a thing as "percent similarity" when comparing text-vectors; instead, there's 'cosine similarity', which in Gensim will give a value from -1.0 to 1.0. Many people pretend this is a "percent similarity" especially after scaling it to 0.0 to 1.0, but that's not a good mental model, as it can mislead people into thinking that this is some true absolute comparison (as opposed to a scale heavily influenced mby many choices).

Comment: If the two texts you want to compare were already separate texts in your training data, each with their own unique tags, you can get their cosine-similarity with something like `model.dv.similarity(tag_1, tag_2)`. If they're new texts that weren't in your training data, you would have to use `.infer_vector()` to get text vectors, than use other math code to compare the vectors.

Comment: Sir Thank you so much please can you have a look at the edited question. I added the code maybe now it will  clear more situation to you.

Comment: Looking at your code, there’s no reason to call `train()` twice. Also, you should use the same tokenization (changing raw text to a list-of-words) for both your training data & any later texts for inference. That said, `model. dv.most_similar(positive=[inferred_vector])` should give you a ranked list of the training texts that are most-similar to your target text. (Whether the results are any good will depend on the sufficiency of your data, proper parameter choices, etc.)

Comment: Yeah, thanks I updated the code. Have you seen the output I had?  Actually, when I put the same paragraph to target_file which I have in train_data I got the same output and if changing the target paragraph which is not relevant to train_data output is not changing. So how I know it's finding the similarity correctly or not?
`sim = model. dv.most_similar(positive=[inferred_vector],  topn=len(model.dv))`

Comment: You won't get a meaningful model of 50 dimensions from just 3 training examples. This algorithm, & others like it, need lots of training data.